# Entity Framework - Table structure, navigating many descendants, etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-1.1

So I'm rewriting a dated application and trying to structure things the right way. I have a Category > Product > Part > Options basic structure, but there are multiple layers in each and I don't know how to simplify my data structure, and navigate children effectively.

[image: table structure]

I feel like it's a little complicated for e-commerce, but we have a multitude of product, part, and part options.

So just for kicks I tried to see if I could round up all the data from a top level category all the way down to the swatches for the different part options to see if an entire page could display the entire category/product line at once (I know not to do this in production). The immediate problem I ran into was including all the descendants in my LINQ queries, as there are several that require intermediary objects due to the extra columns in the relational tables. That's necessary, I understand, but it gets messy quickly as this is setup to have a potentially unlimited number of category/subcategory levels. For example:

```
IQueryable<Category> Categories = Context.CategoryHierarchies
    .Where(w => w.ParentCategoryId == null)
    .Where(w => w.Active == true)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Sort)
    .Select(s => s.Category)
    .Include("ParentCategories")
    .Include("CategoryProducts.Product.ProductParts.Part")
    .Include("SubCategories.Category.CategoryProducts.Product.ProductParts.part")
    .Include("SubCategories.Category.SubCategories.Category.CategoryProducts.Product.ProductParts.part")
```

I didn't do lambas on the includes to keep things shorter for the paste. Now obviously this could go on even longer as I didn't get into the part options, but from there, I would potentially need to have 3 more lines for each level of part option, right? Like:

```
.Include("SubCategories.Category.CategoryProducts.Product.ProductParts.Part.PartMaterials.Swatch")
```

All the way down. Yikes. So for my question, when I'm loading my ViewModels into a view, and I want to access categories, products, and potentially parts, is there a better way to do this? I have a view that does a foreach on each level that I can, but it starts getting tedious real fast. Do I just load them all as separate objects in the view model and access them directly, and populated through separate queries? I'm pretty new to this and would really appreciate anyone's suggestions.

I did see the .NET Core .ThenInclude() stuff, which does look helpful, but I wasn't completely sure it would clean things up that much. It's a lot of descending.

Comment: I think it will be more cleaner if you use SQL View that will be mapped to an class but EF Core don't work actually with SQL Views. Anyway I think you should move your question in this web site => https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SQL View may help or create your own Repository pattern on top of Entity Framework to hide the includes from the outside world.